# How to diff a very long csv with a very long txt

Tags: list, csv, compare, diff, txt

I have two CSVs:

- **beta.csv**: where multiple NPCs have multiple items (some items are currently invalid)

  ```
  NPC,Item
  NPC 1,Item 1
  NPC 1,Item 2
  NPC 2,Item 1
  NPC 2,Item 3
  NPC 3,Item 2
  NPC 4,Item 1
  NPC 4,Item 4
  NPC 4,Item 5
  ```
- **live.csv**: a list of currently valid items:

  ```
  Item
  Item 1
  Item 3
  Item 5
  ```

Since Item 2 and Item 4 don't exist in live.csv, I want to remove any row in beta.csv with those items.

I want the result CSV to look like:

```
NPC,Item
NPC 1,Item 1
NPC 2,Item 1
NPC 2,Item 3
NPC 4,Item 1
NPC 4,Item 5
```

I'm really not sure how I should proceed here as I'm not used to diffing files so any help will be most welcome!

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: You want to filter rows in the NPC table, based on the non-existence of rows in the item table.  I'd (a) build a map, set, vector or array from the item table then (b) read each row of NPC table and discard rows that refer to items missing from the map.  Easy to do in a programming language.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what exactly you have and want. But based on the example and assuming you have the "live items" as list in a text file you might get something out of `grep -Ff live-item-list.txt beta.csv`

Answer (score 0):

I see this like *list suppression*: you want to drop some rows from A if they don't exist in B.

When dealing with CSV files, using a real CSV parser will make the results much more reliable.  You could write a very small program in Python to accomplish this, or you could use a CSV-aware command-line tool like GoCSV and its [join subcommand](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/#join).

Join "joins two CSVs using an inner (default), left, right, or outer join, based on the equality of elements in a column.".

In your case, the default inner join will keep rows only if Item exists in both files.  Since live is a subset of beta, live will be the limiting factor when determining which rows from beta to include:

```
gocsv join -c Item beta.csv live.csv
NPC,Item,Item
NPC 1,Item 1,Item 1
NPC 2,Item 1,Item 1
NPC 2,Item 3,Item 3
NPC 4,Item 1,Item 1
NPC 4,Item 5,Item 5
```

Join *zips* the CSVs together (in addition to the joining logic), so we get all three columns.

That can be trimmed down using the [select subcommand](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/#select) ("extract specified columns"), and the output of join can be *piped* into select:

```
gocsv join -c Item beta.csv live.csv | gocsv select -c 1,2
NPC,Item
NPC 1,Item 1
NPC 2,Item 1
NPC 2,Item 3
NPC 4,Item 1
NPC 4,Item 5
```

For join we specified the column "Item" by name since it's shared by both files. For select, we need to specify only the first and second columns (`1,2`) since the name "Item" is repeated.

Just redirect that to get the final file, called output.csv in the following example:

```
gocsv join -c Item beta.csv live.csv | gocsv select -c 1,2 > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a join in [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.8.0/installing-miller/)

```
mlr --csv join -j  Item -f beta.csv then reorder -f NPC,Item live.csv >out.csv
```

to have

```
NPC,Item
NPC 1,Item 1
NPC 2,Item 1
NPC 4,Item 1
NPC 2,Item 3
NPC 4,Item 5
```